# How to create hover text on image slider android?

Tags: android

I have an image slider with the bottom code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private final int[] mImages = new int[] {
            R.drawable.chiang_mai,
            R.drawable.himeji,
            R.drawable.petronas_twin_tower,
            R.drawable.ulm
    };

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position, final Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final Context context = MainActivity.this;
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        final int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(this.mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(final View view, final Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    final ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final CirclePageIndicator circleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    circleIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

    final TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    tvText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bodyText));

    }
 }
```

And this is the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
 <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So I need to set a text Hover on the Viewpager so that when I swipe it, it will show up for a specific picture. How can I create a hover text on this image slider while making it run automatically for some specific time, and after a swipe show a hover text.

Comment: Let me see if I get this straight: You want to show a text (possible a Toast?) when the user swipes away the `Viewpager`? You also want to `swipe` the `ViewPager` away if a certain time has passed and the user has not performed an action?

Comment: Are you referring to a Toast?

Comment: @Sunil No i mean a text view to show a text on my View Pager , and change the text when swipe , like description of every image

Comment: @GeorgeD No i dont mean Toast, i want to show a text View on the View pager , and Describe some about the images , and change the text and image with swipe

Answer (score 0):

Have you just one XML Layout? If you've two it makes it quite alot easier to work with.

So this layout below is where the actual image slider will be place on the Home Fragment in this case.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.****.****.HomeFragment"
    android:background="#000000"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="204dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Secondly, this XML Layout below is the Layout for the ViewPager itself. As you can see it is made up of an ImageView and a TextView. With the TextView placed on top of the ImageView.

Hope this helps a bit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:text="******"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#17baef" />
</RelativeLayout>
```